# I want to access .sql file format on the computer without using the internet

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, datagridview, database-connection

I need to access data from the database and manipulate the data. I can do this through the internet, however I need to make it so that the data can be accessed on the computer that the program runs without having internet connection.

The current method I'm using is displayed below with the code:

```
Dim dbDataSet2 As New DataTable
Sqlconn = New MySqlConnection
Sqlconn.ConnectionString="server=xx.xx.xx;userid=root;password=xxxxxx;database=xxxxxx"
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As New BindingSource

Try
Sqlconn.Open()    'open connection
Dim query As String

query = "SELECT * FROM bbs_test.test"

command = New MySqlCommand(query, Sqlconn)
SDA.SelectCommand = command
SDA.Fill(dbDataSet2)
bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet2
DataGridView_array.DataSource = bSource
SDA.Update(dbDataSet2)

          Sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Is there a was to change this, so the file location is using a path like C: \ ......   or something similar

Also the file gets updated as well from time to time and the format of the file is .sql

Please can anyone help me

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely the server address in the connection string.  To make it connect to your local SQL Server engine, you can simply set the address to either `(local)` or `.`, for instance:

```
Sqlconn.ConnectionString="server=.;userid=root;password=xxxxxx;database=xxxxxx"
```

Comment: You can only connect to it if it exists.  In order for that code to work, you would need to have a SQL Server running on your local machine.  It must contain a database by that name and it must allow login with the given user name and password.  If it's not properly configured, obviously you will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: A `.sql` file is almost certainly not a SQL Server database.  It's probably just a SQL script.  Determining how to import that into a local database engine would completely depend upon which engine generated the script, what it contains, and what engine you are trying to import it into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local IP address of lan adapter or IP address of localhost (127.0.0.1) it work without internet connection because everything is on local computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a local - physical database like Access.

https://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/how-to-connect-ms-access-with-vb-net-using-oledb-2/

Comment: the source file has .accdb can .sql  work for the file format.  I'm asking this because, I tried binding the data to the datagridview and it didn't allow .sql to work

Comment: What do you mean. What are you using the sql file for? To import the database?

Comment: the data from the machine is stored in a .sql file format and I want to be able to access that data using the computer that is used to control the machine which doesn't have internet connection.  The computer uses ports to control the machine.      I want to use that data to do some calculations.

Comment: Import the data in Access using the sql file.

Comment: could you provide a guidance link, where I can get some information on this